# Android, how to update a textView in secondary activity from BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity class (WiFiTest), inside which I have defined a private class (WiFiScanReceiver) which extends BroadcastReceiver.
In the onReceive() method of WiFiScanReceiver I would like to update a widget (position TextView) defined in a secondary activity (Positioning).

When I try to retrive the position

```
TextView (

    position = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.position);
),
```

I always get a null value, even when the secondary activity (Positioning) is active.

Any Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register another `BroadcastReceiver` in 2nd `Activity` and manage it's views there.

Comment: Thanks. I did just try it. It's a WiFiReceiver: should I unregister the main activity receiver before registering my secondary receiver? I get this exception in logcat: "05-10 13:28:10.564: ERROR/ActivityThread(737): Activity koine.marcos.wifidemo.Positioning has leaked IntentReceiver koine.marcos.wifidemo.Positioning$WiFiScanReceiver@44ff30d8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?" ?

Comment: You should unregister every of your receivers in `onPause` or `onStop`, please read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html